# How is this query write correctly?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like below. I want to create a table and convert null values to 0. But my query failed. How can I write it correctly ?

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_2 
AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM TABLE_1 1 = 2;

INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PHONE_NUMBER,
                     HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, SALARY, NVL(COMMISSION_PCT, 0), MANAGER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID) 
    SELECT * 
    FROM TABLE_1;
```

Comment: *"my query failed."* is not very helpful. Please **describe what happens** when you run your code, including any error messages you get.

Comment: Although I will guess that the problem is the CTAS statement is missing the keyword WHERE before the `1 = 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Both your statements contain syntax errors.

The CREATE TABLE ... SELECT AS statement requires a valid query: your query is missing the WHERE keyword.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_2 
AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM TABLE_1 where 1 = 2;
```

Insert statements can have two projections. The optional project is the list of columns in the target table. Your list includes `NVL(COMMISSION_PCT, 0)` which is not a valid column name, but a declaration of the data manipulation you wish to apply to the column from the **source** table. Consequently you need to include it in the projection of the SELECT statement.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2 
    SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PHONE_NUMBER,
                     HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, SALARY, NVL(COMMISSION_PCT, 0), MANAGER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID  
    FROM TABLE_1;
```

I have published a working demo on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=86b25783cf084a3ac58e937154acfa21).

Answer (score -1):

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE_2(EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PHONE_NUMBER,   HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID)
 SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PHONE_NUMBER, HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, SALARY, NVL(COMMISSION_PCT,0), MANAGER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID
FROM TABLE_1
```

Comment: I get an error "table or view does not exist"

Comment: Pity. Have you executed CREATE TABLE TABLE_2 AS  SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 1=2;